# Command or program to get width, height + XMP tags?

Tags: windows, command-line, image-processing

I have a problem while working in Windows command line whereby I am trying to get width, height and XMP tags (where applicable) from a large number of image files in a variety of formats (JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF, and TIFF).

I have settled on exiv2 as follows:

```
exiv2 -K Xmp.dc.subject -K Exif.Photo.PixelXDimension -K Exif.Photo.PixelYDimension [file]
```

This works just fine for JPEG, but for WEBP it outputs nothing, presumably as WEBP doesn't have EXIF data.

The documentation doesn't seem to provide any options for fetching dimensions other than from EXIF data.

How can I modify the exiv2 options to get dimensions for file types other than JPEG?

Comment: I’m voting to leave this closed, for the same reason that it was originally closed.  This might be a candidate for [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but read their tour before posting there.  At the very least, you should list the formats you need to handle.  If you have specific timing requirements, try to quantify them.

Comment: Well, maybe I will try over at Software Recs as you suggest.